# Delete feed comments in chatter using visualforce

Tags: visualforce, chatter

Can we delete the feedcomments using visualforce ?

Answer (score 0):

Re you [other question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/54132/is-there-anyway-to-post-feedcomment-dynamically), you can also delete comments via the [ConnectAPI](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcodepre/Content/apex_ConnectAPI_ChatterFeeds_static_methods.htm#apex_ConnectAPI_ChatterFeeds_deleteComment) if you know the Comment Id:

> ConnectAPI.ChatterFeeds.deleteComment(NULL, [commentId]);

Comment: I wanna delete the comment that I posted previously..

Comment: I dono how to the comment id that I posted previously.    please help on this

Comment: How do you plan to identify the comments you want to delete? Via a search? a Query? What have you tried so far?