# Is there anyway to post feedcomment dynamically

Tags: visualforce, chatter, feeditem, feedcomment

Is there anyway to post a feed comment dynamically for the particular feeditems in visualforce?

Please help!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if understand your question, but if you want to post a comment, you can use:

Chatter Rest API: 
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/chatterapi/

Apex Controller:
http://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_feedcomment.htm#topic-title

Comment: If you are accessing Chatter from Apex directly, you are better off using the ConnectAPI, since that is just a namespace in Apex

Answer (score 1):

You can use the PostComment Method on the [ConnectAPI](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcodepre/Content/apex_ConnectAPI_ChatterFeeds_static_methods.htm#apex_ConnectAPI_ChatterFeeds_postCommentToFeedElement_1) (which is effectively an Apex enabled version of the Chatter REST API) if you know the FeedItem/Feed Element you are trying to post to:
From docs:

> ConnectApi.Comment comment =
>   ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.postCommentToFeedElement(null,
>   '0D5D0000000KuGh', 'I agree with the proposal.' );

Where first param is Community Id, second is the Feed Element Id, and final param is the actual text.

I also did a session at DF14 which you can see [here](http://dreamforce.vidyard.com/watch/mMhfaAIPm7Mc5TxBBlk5DQ) explaining how to get started with the ConnectAPI

Comment: I wanna post a feed comment dynamically to the particular post.For that what I hve to do?